# How to use Angular2 dependency injection with javascript decorators?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angular, ecmascript-6

I tried to inject a service (TodoStore) into my component (TodoList) but failed with decorators. The only way it works is with constructor parameter decorators

```
constructor(@Inject(TodoStore) store)
```

which is not valid ES7 as i know.
I tried to put the inject before the class or before constructor function, neither way worked with Webpack.
My current most standard compliant solution is

```
static get parameters() {
  return [[TodoStore]];
}
```

My question is there a way with decorators in valid ES6/ES7 to inject dependencies?

Comment: For now the most convenient way is to use the static getter

Comment: Isn't there a tag for ES6 and ES7? someone should create them if not.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't need to use the `@Inject` annotation. Your service needs to have a `@Injectable` annotation.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {
  (...)
}
```

To be able to inject it into your component simply add it then in the parameters of its constructor and into its providers list:

```
import {TodoStore} from './todoStore';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  providers: [ TodoStore ],
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
export class TodoListComponent {
  constructor(service:TodoStore) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It is already a \@Component which is \@Injectable. The constructor you suggest is Typescript specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {TodoStore} from './todoStore';

@Component(...)
export class TodoListComponent {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  ...
}

// Workaround for parameter annotations
TodoListComponent.parameters = [new Inject(TodoStore)];
```

Comment: Technically it is the same as the static getter, just outside the declaration.

Comment: This is mostly accurate, only difference here is that you don't need to use Inject at all. If you just put the World class into the parameters, then the injector will take care of instantiating it for you.